# Database calculations are wrong

Tags: sql-server

Here is what I'm setting:

```
result = price / (case when tax = 0 then @tax1h / 100 else @tax2 / 100 end + 1)
```

These are the values:

```
price = 17.5
tax = 1
tax2 = 6
```

17.5 / (6 / 100 + 1) = 16.5

And this returns 17.5 Why is this happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html):

```
select (6 / 100 + 1)
```

The result of the above is 1.

However, the result of:

```
select (6 / 100.0 + 1)
```

Is 1.06.